# SQL "WITH" Clause

Tags: sql-server

Is there any other way to reorganize this instead of using the "WITH" clasue?

Here is the code:

```
    CREATE table #TEMP 
    (
            RowNum int identity, 
            ItemId int, 
            LevelId int, 
            Id int,         
            Depth int
    )

    ;WITH CTEAlias
    (ItemId, LevelId, Id, Existingdepth) as 
    (
        Select ItemId, LevelId, Id, 0 as ExistingDepth
        From tblNavItems 
        Where NavLevelId In 
         (Select NavLevelId 
          From tblNavLevels 
          Where SoltnId = @FromSoltnID 
            And NavTypeId = @NavTypeId1) 
       And ParentId = -1
        Union All
        Select tni.ItemId, tni.LevelId, tni.Id, ExistingDepth+1
        From tblNavItems as tni
           Join CTEAlias as ca
              On tni.Id = ca.ItemId
        Where tni.LevelId In 
          (Select NavLevelId 
           From tblNavLevels 
           Where SoltnId = @FromSoltnID 
              And NavTypeId = @NavTypeId1)
    )
    INSERT INTO #TEMP(ItemId, LevelId, Id,Depth)
    Select * FROM CTEAlias Order BY Id
```

I do not want "With" clause in it NOR alias. 
Could please let me know if there is any other way to rewrite this maybe using two tables?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the CTE?

Comment: What is your goal? Performance? Prettier code? Something else?

Comment: @JNK Probably using a version of SQL Server that doesn't support them. And since you're recursively joining the CTE I don't think you will be able to use a sub-query. You'll probably need to resort to temp tables instead.

Comment: @Yuck - maybe not since the OP doesn't seem to even understand what a `CTE` is ('With clause')

Comment: How would I do it with temp tables?

Comment: @JNK Perhaps that's the reason in itself then :)

Comment: You have a recursive CTE. Rewriting it without a CTE is ugly (unless there is a fixed depth) but knock yourself out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175801(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? If SQL Server, what version?

Comment: @user1047883 Again, **WHY** do you want to remove the CTE?

Comment: Thank you guys for the info. I guess CTE is the easiest way to go around this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is to select data into temp table, you can do that as below without "WITH".

```
CREATE table #TEMP (  dt1 datetime, id1 int)
INSERT INTO #TEMP(dt1, id1)
SELECT * FROM (
            Select ab, bc
            From UY420 
            where bc=100000
        ) a
```